# What happens when a user enters a value that is smaller than 1 wei?

Tags: ether

Wei is the smallest denomination, and any ETH amount can be converted to wei by multiplying the value by 10^18. However, say a user enters a very very small amount of ETH to send, say a decimal value with 19 zeroes (ie, 0.00000000000000000001). When converted to wei, this
gives a fraction of 1 wei, namely 0.01 wei. Theoretically, you can get any infinitesimely small value.

Howe does the Ethereum protocol handle values smaller than 1 wei? Does it just disregard them or floor them down to 0 ETH?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, everything rounds down in Ethereum.  so you just put in zero